# Trouble understanding the hardware debugger concept in an MCU

Tags: microcontroller, debugging

When we write a program code to be used for a MCU in C and compile it by using an IDE, the IDE by the help of the compiler already shows us all the possible mistakes. For instance, if I type:

```
int x = 2
```

The IDE will show me an error such as:

> error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘return’

It seems the IDE together with the compiler already debugs and shows all the errors in our code.

Now after we are ready with the compiled code we upload this binary program(.HEX or.bin) into the chip via an ISP(by using an external programmer) or a chip's built in bootloader program.

Some external programmers are also called programmer/debugger.

But what are they debugging at this point? Didn't we already finish the debugging when we are done with compiling our code by using the IDE? I really don't understand what extra does the hardware debugging.

Comment: What happens if you wrote some code that could not be solved at compile time?

Comment: What do you mean by solved? You mean compiler might not be able to detect some errors?

Comment: @atmnt Certainly. The compiler isn't psychic--you can write completely valid code that compiles but doesn't do what you want it to do. Don't confuse debugging with syntax- and lexical-checking.

Comment: @AndreyAkhmetov I don't have deep knowledge on the subject but is it possible to flash the program without debugging? Or is it prohibited? For example this Arduino boards mostly are programmed via bootloader. Does that mean there is no such hardware debugging? And is that risky?

Comment: @atmnt Hard to say because we don't even agree on what debugging is. You flash the program and it runs. If it runs and you're happy, you're done. If it runs but doesn't do so properly, you use an in-circuit debugger to figure out what the program is *actually* doing. The Arduino *does* have a hardware debugger--using an in-circuit programmer with DebugWire support, plugged into the in-circuit programming port, allows you to debug code running on the atmega328 chip that makes up the core of the arduino.

Comment: @AndreyAkhmetov You mean the hardware debugging is done only via ISP? Or it is also performed when we use bootloader(the common way)? I cannot find neat explanations of these concepts. When I google in-circuit debugger arduino I cannot find any photo which shows such HW debugger section on the board.

Comment: No compiler can detect logical errors.  It can't even detect if the program will ever [exit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), as proved by Alan Turing. The controller usually does what you told it to do, but that may well not be what you wanted it to do. Think about trying to get a complex algorithm to work properly- you would like to see all the steps, code coverage, and intermediate results, rather than just viewing the unexpected output and spending hours or days trying to figure out why it isn't working correctly.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I think Integrated Development Environment is hiding whether the error is compiler error or debugger error. Im not sure but what I got from the above comments for example Arduino IDE is already communicating with the debugger on the board even though I cannot find where it is. I didn't know the IDE was also communicating with the HW debugger. I thought the IDE does only the compilation of teh C code.

Comment: Arduino as an environment is quite different from using the same hardware with an ISP debugger and, say, Atmel Studio, but there should be no "hiding" involved.

Comment: for an Arduino, `serial.print()` command is a form of hardware debugger ... other platforms also have a way to print data to the serial port .... think about how such a function can be useful

Comment: @atmnt The bootloader simply jumps to executing your code, after optionally receiving new code over some sort of configuration port. ISP can be used to flash a device or debug an existing program in flash by interacting with a debug controller that allows stepping/breakpoints and reading RAM/registers. The two are mostly orthogonal (i.e. on AVR, I could have put a program into flash using a bootloader, ISP, or HVPP, and still debug it as long as I have an appropriate debugging tool)

Answer (score 4):

Syntax errors and runtime errors are two very different things. For example, the compiler will happily create an executable from

```
int x = 10;
int y = 0;
int z = x / y;
```

As there are no **syntax errors**, but now you have a **runtime error** (divide by zero) that only comes to light when you *run the code*. You also have logic errors that can only be found at runtime by running through a test (expected input should have an expected output), which is where debugging comes in handy (see what values are passed in, step through the logic, etc).

For example, if you expect the function to provide a square of a number, but code it like this:

```
int GetSquare(int x)
{
    return x ^ 2;
}
```

(Assuming ANSI C, you may think from other languages that the `^` is the exponent operator, when it is actually the XOR operator).

This happily compiles, runs, and probably produces some really weird results. Now you need to step through the debugger while the program is running. **This is a logic error**, and your testing should find this, but the compiler will not.

There are also hardware bugs and quirks that you need to use the debugger for in an embedded environment. This is handy if you couple it with a logic scope or oscilloscope to determine the signals you are sending versus the expected behavior. Occasionally a hardware bug will come up that you need to code around and having the tools to determine that it is *not* a fault of the code is of great help.

Comment: Thanks for the nice clear answer. But why would float GetSquare produce weird results? And can you give also an example where hardware debugger would find the bug. If we use HW debugger in embedded system is it the debugger or we find the bug?

Comment: And your first example int z = x / y; is giving compiler error not debugging error: I tried here https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler Isnt it?

Comment: The "weird result" Ron Beyer is referring to is that his example GetSquare function returns the value of x with the least significant bit inverted by the Boolean XOR operator `^`:  GetSquare(0) returns 2, GetSquare(1) returns 3, GetSquare(2) returns 0, GetSquare(3) returns 1, GetSquare(4) returns 6, GetSquare(5) returns 7. The name GetSquare clearly implies it's *intended* to return x squared, so the code looks right, even though `^` is not the exponent operator in C/C++. Validating that the code meets the design intentions, requires writing additional *unit testing* code.

Comment: 30% of all the ATE code I write, no matter what language I use, is all about handling most any software or hardware error. Every major loop has timeout and abort code added.

Comment: @atmnt It gives a runtime error after you hit "run", which is not a compiler error. Since you can't run (outside an emulator) embedded code without the device, this isn't something you would catch until you ran it. And MarkU is right about the `GetSquare` strange results so I won't repeat it. I think you are confused on what is a "bug" and what is a syntax error. The compiler finds syntax errors only, "bugs" are found when you run the code and the compiler does not find them, such as the `GetSquare` method I gave as an example.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax error is a (programming language) thing.  Like spelling and grammar.  When you write a novel or textbook in a language you should follow those rules.  The CONTENT of the book is a separate thing from the syntax, is it math textbook what are you teaching, etc.  The programming language syntax is the first thing then there is the functionality of the program.  What it actually does, you can have the syntax correct but the program is full of bugs.

Traditionally hardware did not have built in debuggers, in the processor/chip.  Various techniques from software approaches to possibly incorrectly named in circuit emulators, for example I used one that the actual processor sat on top, a ribbon cable went into a workstation, that i would use the term interposer, the signals from the processor essentially went through special hardware on a card in the workstation, so that everything (relevant) between the processor and board could be interfered with and/or monitored, it didnt emulate the processor necessarily just provided a way to control the processor and the board.

Today we often see OCD on chip debuggers, built into the processor itself will be some debugging features.  You may sometimes find features like the ability to stop and start, single step. Ability to read/write registers or memory.  Set or clear breakpoints.  Set or clear watchpoints (memory/address accesses).  Varies by processor and how it works varies as well, some stop the processor then use special logic, I have seen one/some inject instructions into an active pipeline in order to debug.  This on chip logic will then need an interface to the outside world, often JTAG but not always.

You can still debug your program without these on chip features, by modifying the program.  adding print statements or blink an led, which works on pretty much all platforms, but yes it definitely affects the program and program flow by doing this, depends on the nature of the bug.  before the on chip debuggers, processors would (and some still do) have a breakpoint instruction, if not then an undefined instruction with an undefined instruction handler solution.  a "debugger" would modify the program in memory (helps to be running from ram not rom/flash) by setting the "breakpoint" using an undefined instruction, then handler would be part of the overall set of tools, and the host would then see that breakpoint or undefined instruction, then could have code run on the processor to extract register or memory values, etc.

Another extreme was or was potentially jtag in its original form as boundry scan.  with great pain you could control all the inputs to the processor, single stepping the clock, data busses, etc.  Not recommended, but was possible.

These on chip debuggers and/or other logic features will often allow the user to load programs.  Some ip/processor solutions you come in through the debugger (a host program talks to the chips OCD) where it can worst case create single bus transactions directly or through injecting/placing instructions, that can then interact with the in application flash peripheral and program the flash with your firmware.  Some designs you stop the processor (ip/chip specific) and there is dedicated logic through some interface (spi, i2c, proprietary) that is specific to that processor and the protocol that rides on top of that combines to allow the host software to load your firmware into the flash.  ISP is a good term for it, but not used by that term by all product families.

So you can come in through special in system logic in the chip that has direct access to the flash (or memory in some cases for development/debugging).  You can come in through an on chip debugger and essentially create processor bus cycles, anything the processor can do you can do through this interface if the processor/software can program the flash then you can too.  Note that it is not uncommon to actually download a small program into ram and use it to actually do the programming as it can be dozens of times faster, download the program then download the firmware to ram, then ask the program to write that firmware to the flash, check for the program to finish, repeat as needed, done.  Because we dont use the classic intel(/compatible) parallel flash, software tools dont necessarily want to know the custom nuances of each chip, so with generic tools like openocd you may or may not find flash support, someone has to take the time to add it.  but you can yourself write the program that gets downloaded along with your application firmware to ram then run that using a tool like openocd to load and run it.  making your solution ide/tool independent.

two pin solutions have been around for a while, but we are seeing some new ones take over a multi-pin (spi, jtag, etc) solution from that vendor in the past. using a two pin solution to talk to an on chip debugger that can do many things vs strictly rom/flash programming and then you are on your own for debugging are happening with certainly the arm based products which are taking over the market, size/price/power vs performance.

Developers rarely want to know any of this they want a high level api programming approach and a bunch of magic buried in an IDE, they dont care.  So mcu vendors that want to sell product to a wider array of customers need turnkey solutions, so they will develop or contract out a full IDE experience.  Implementation varies widely.  And they feel the need to improve the tools every few years, you gotta use the new one get rid of the old.

These are generally an IDE with solutions for developing software, connection to the api/library for the product family you are interested in and support for at least the debuggers they sell sometimes support for ones they dont, so you can point and click your way through, select the part/family, write some code, click some buttons and it just works.  click some more buttons and you can single step through the code, examine memory/registers, etc.  all the magic happening through the above types of interfaces along with compiler/assembler/linker toolchains either developed by/for them or a generic gnu or other similar toolchain bundled with the ide.

The better documented chips/families (some brands are better than others, some are pretty bad some are pretty good) describe the possible interfaces into the chip and the protocols used.  the arm based products that are taking over buy arm ip, and then wrap their chip around it so a lot of the in circuit features come from arm not the chip vendor, the chip vendor simply needs to place a couple of pins for SWD access and have an in application way to program the flash.  but even there you will find that some vendors like NXP and ST have built in debuggers that you can communicate with via spi, usb, serial, and doesnt use the ocd at all.  some have more solutions than that.

what is also very common is a multi-chip solution, when you buy many of these evalutaion/development boards.  st nucleo or ti launchpads, etc.  There is the target mcu, the one you are evaluating, then there is a debug mcu, one that runs firmware from the board/chip vendor.  And the protocol that rides on usb between the ide/host and the board is talking to the debug mcu, the debug mcu firmware will use one of the chips solutions, for example swd into an arm based mcu.  So there is an added higher level layer on top of this.  many of the st discovery/nucleo boards you can use the debugger end of it on other mcus not on that pcb, you can use it as a generic debugger.  ARM is trying to get into this game with cmsis and mbed and they have a debugger they want to push similar to this a front end and common debug header to be used generically for arm based products.  an IDE can then ride on top of all of this and use this higher level protocol/interface to access the chip/core.  as can standalone tools.

As the developer you are free to use a turnkey IDE, or a text editor and command line tools (some of which you may have developed yourself) or anything in between. Very rarely are you limited/tied to an IDE, and if the product vendor (not your boss) has that limitation, I would find a different product or vendor.

BACK TO THE POINT.

Your example is a compiler syntax error it is only the first step in debugging, like getting spelling or grammar right when writing a paper/book.  Once you get past the spelling and the grammar you now have the content.  The program, what it does.

```
int x = 2;
```

correct syntax, but the value was supposed to be a 3.  That is a bug, needs to be a 3.  Impossible for the compiler to know the correct value to use to initialize that variable.  Just like the "authorities" on the english language that define the spelling and syntax (more conventions than hard rules as they are constantly evolving) cant possibly know what your paper/book/stackexchange question is going to be, they simply define the language you provide the content. I may have bad grammer in this answer, or sometimes correct, may have some correct spelling and some incorrect.  And I may have used the wrong word here and their (grin), despite the correct spelling.  debugging goes way beyond the spelling and punctuation of the language.

Possibly easy to see visually, most bugs, lets say all, can be seen visually once you know what to look for and where to look, but some/many it is easier to run the code and debug that way.  Run the code and see that a value is wrong, then work backward to figure out how the value got wrong and possibly find the line above that maybe should have been a 3 instead of a 2.  Or sometimes it is many lines of code combined as a whole that create the bug and not just one character on one line.  There is no universal way to find bugs, it is a talent/art form in and of itself.  There is no universal tool/solution (debugger, single step, memory watch, etc) either, for any universal solution you come up with I can make a bug it cant find.  Dont get sold on these one size fits all concepts.  Debugging is work and you have to learn to find/use/create tools. And it definitely goes beyond the compiler and language syntax.